# Visual studio 2010 WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I can add the Chart control located in Data group of toolbox if i create a windows form application..but if i create a wpf application i cant!

it is disabled.. what can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you can use WindowsFormsHost and create Chart in code-behind

Comment: yes i found out that this is possible and had success!!But the client says that this requires XP SP3 which will cause problems to old computers!

Comment: I've succesfully installed Chart control from link: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=130F7986-BF49-4FE5-9CA8-910AE6EA442C&displaylang=en#SystemRequirements on XP SP2 with  .NET 3.5 SP1

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535) or a third-party WPF Chart control (Google it).